# <script> tag at bottom causing $(document).ready to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, single-page-application

I was following the snippets from html5boilerplate.com (as well as something that is recommended by yahoo) that we should put the scripts at the bottom of the page (of my site's main page).

I am also following SPI (Single page interface) - meaning I will load the content area only via ajax for any new page visit.

My page structure is..

```
<body>
<header />
<div id="content" />
<footer />
</body>
```

Now issue is ..
I load JQuery at the end of main page. But I need some javascript to get executed on the child page which would be loaded in content div. So if I write 
    `$(document).ready(..)`
in the child page, it will crib about "$ is not defined".

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you loading the scripts files out of the html scope?

Comment: What does *child page* mean when there's only one page?

Comment: @punit <script> tag is the last tag inside <body> tag.

Comment: @alvaro-g-vicario By child page, I mean, the page that gets included / ajaxed into the content div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your jquery include into your header. Then it will work. As long you don't need a very high performance site you don't need such performance hacks. And you should understand how and why the hacks work before using them. If you really want to include jquery at the bottom of the script you have to put all your JS code below the jquery include.

Comment: I was also thinking on the same line that I will include the jquery (at least) in the header. But, wanted opinion from others.